# Dúvida PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, delphi

Bom dia. Tenho a seguinte SQL funcionando:

```
Select g.galeria,g.tipo,g.finalidade,count(p.galeria) as total
from pessoas p
full join galerias g
on p.galeria = g.galeria
group by g.galeria,g.tipo,g.finalidade
order by g.galeria
```

Contudo preciso mostrar esse resultado em uma linha contínua (string), tentei assim:

```
Select string_agg(g.tipo::text || ' ' || g.galeria::text || ' (' || g.finalidade::text || '): ' || count(p.galeria) as total, ',') from galerias g
full join pessoas p
on p.galeria = g.galeria
```

Surge o aviso: **ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"**

Alguma ideia?

---

Grato pelas respostas Marcos, Ricardo e Piovezan...mas agora surge outro erro:

```
Select string_agg(g.tipo::text || ' ' || g.galeria::text || ' (' || g.finalidade::text || '): ' || count(p.galeria) , ',') as total from galerias g
FULL JOIN pessoas p
ON p.galeria = g.galeria
```

*ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested*

---

Grato Anonimo...sua sugestão funcionou com pequenas alterações:

```
WITH quantidade as(
    Select g.galeria, g.tipo, g.finalidade, count(p.galeria) as total
    from presos p
    full join galerias g
    on p.galeria = g.galeria
    group by g.galeria,g.tipo,g.finalidade
) 
Select string_agg(g.tipo::text || ' ' || g.galeria::text || ' (' || g.finalidade::text || '): ' || q.total, ',') 
from galerias g full join quantidade q on (q.galeria = g.galeria and q.tipo = g.tipo and q.finalidade = g.finalidade)
WHERE g.galeria <= 50
AND g.situacao = 'ATIVA'
group by g.galeria,g.tipo,g.finalidade
order by g.galeria
```

Agradeço a todos pela colaboração!

Comment: `count(p.galeria) as total` não deveria fechar o parênteses do `string_agg` antes do "as"?

Comment: É esse `count(p.galeria) as total`, pequeno gafanhoto, que eu acho que deveria ser só `count(p.galeria)` e se a intenção é mudar o nome do resultado para `total` (que é o que o `as` faz) tem que ficar pra fora assim, `count(p.galeria), ',') as total`

Comment: Sobre o erro 'aggregate function calls [...]', você está usando um count() dentro de um string_agg()... Isso está causando a falha, para evitar, vc deveria usar alguma estratégia. Sugiro uma subquery para o total.

Comment: @Jones713 Entenda o funcionamento do site. É uma pergunta por vez, resolveu essa você aceita a resposta que resolveu (clica no sinalzinho à esquerda da resposta) e se der outro problema você abre outra pergunta. O conceito do site é Q&A e não fórum. É assim que se marca o "Resolvido" e não no título.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi o resultado desejado mas creio que a utilização de Common Table Expression possa ajuda-lo.

```
WITH quantidade(
    Select g.galeria, g.tipo, g.finalidade, count(p.galeria) as total
    from pessoas p
    full join galerias g
    on p.galeria = g.galeria
    group by g.galeria,g.tipo,g.finalidade
) 
Select string_agg(g.tipo::text || ' ' || g.galeria::text || ' (' || g.finalidade::text || '): ' || q.total, ',') 
from galerias g full join quantidade q on (q.galeria = g.galeria and q.tipo = g.tipo and q.finalidade = g.finalidade);
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá...

Neste trecho

count(p.galeria) **as total**, ',')'

Remova o 'as total'.
Vai ficar assim:

```
... count(p.galeria), ',')
```

E vc pode dar um apelido ao resultado final:

```
... count(p.galeria) , ',') as total
```

Você só deve usar o alias através do 'as' (nesse contexto) quando for alterar o nome da coluna de resultado. Inclusive, você pode omitir também o 'as':

```
... count(p.galeria) , ',') total
```